# Cannot find service in Angular component

Tags: angular

I have created a service file and imported it in my component

```
import { WeatherService } from 'src/app/services/weather.service';
```

but I get an error

> Cannot find module 'src/app/services/weather.service'.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-weather-app

Comment: when you try to share a stackblitz project, please use the link as follow: ```https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dbuebq``` the link you shared only sends to the result, no to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not a problem of angular, the error comes from Stackblitz.

In a typical angular proyect you would have a `tsconfig.json` but it is not a feature that provides Stackblitz, check the issue [here](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/220).

a typical `tsconfig.json` would need to have this `paths` options:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "./*",
        "app/*",
        "../node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
}
```

Right now you should use relative imports:

```
import { WeatherService } from '../../services/weather.service';
```